# Send keystrokes from second keyboard only to programs on second monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, multi-monitor, input-devices

I have a Windows 10 notebook, with a second monitor and second keyboard attached.

I want the second keyboard to send its keys only to the second monitor, and the primary keyboard only to the primary monitor

I know that in Windows, only one program can have the focus at a time.

So when I type something on the external keyboard, the focus should immediately switch to the most recently focused window on the external monitor, and the keystrokes should be sent to that program window.

Likewise, when I type something on the integrated notebook keyboard, the focus should switch to the most recent window on the notebook monitor.

In essence, the keyboards should work as if I had two computers, but with a shared mouse and shared drag&drop.

I think this may be possible with a big custom AutoHotkey script, but I am hoping to find something a little easier to set up.